# the fatal error "fstream.h" file not found happen in Clion?

Tags: c++, clion

When I use the code `#include <ofstream.h>` in my .h file I get this error:

> "fstream.h" file not found

I use the Clion in os x.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you should not include files (system-files), which ends with `.h`, instead do `#include <fstream>`

see: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ofstream